# How to reopen closed incognito tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I can reopen (accidentally) closed tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. However this doesn't seem to work in an "Incognito" window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> **works** on FireFox's Private Browsing. How can we enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> for incognito browsing in Chrome?

Comment: Should be given an option to restore for say 5 to 10 seconds, for accidental closings.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think you can, or even should be able to restore closed tabs in incognito.

Think about it for a second. By switching to incognito mode, you're asking your browser to **not** follow you around and **not** keep local data, and a second later you're asking for a closed tab? Kinda beats the purpose, no?

If you must have this functionality (again, beats the purpose of incognito imho), you can use a session manager (like [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en-US)) and mark it OK to run in incognito.

Comment: Chrome has implemented a "multiple identity" feature which will come to the Developer and Beta builds soon, and I guess this is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Pacerier You can safely install the Chrome Beta because it's really very stable and I've even run the Dev build for more than a year now and have never had any problems! I don't know when, but I'd say in a few weeks?

Comment: Maybe it's changed since you originally answered this question, but incognito mode now lets all its tabs access the same incognito cookies (and deletes them all once you close the last tab). So if you are already letting the browser keep track of your cookies in incognito mode, the question seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Jian, No it didn't change. That was how it always worked. Basically, the computer still **has** the data, so there got to be a way to restore it.

Comment: @slhck, I use incognito because it is "more secure". It's good to know that the shared computer will forget everything about me when I end my session after I've closed all the incognito tabs.

Comment: They should have a timer, say 5 to 10 seconds where you can undo accidental tab closes. I mean during that short period of time is someone else going to start ctrl-shift-t ing your incognito mode windows?

Comment: As Jian said, the Incognito window already keeps your cookies until the end of the session, when it wipes everything. The same should be true for tabs. Firefox does it this way. You can store them until the end of the session then wipe everything.

Answer (score 3):

As [Sexy undo close tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bcennaiejdjpomgmmohhpgnjlmpcjmbg/related) has been removed from Chrome web store, you can try
[Simple Undo Close](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleundoclose/emhohdghchmjepmigjojkehidlielknj?hl=en), which is fork of the Sexy Undo Close Tab extension.
Also take a look at [Simple Undo Recents](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleundorecents/kaiblbjjcealhldhdnjhpjmckgclnbca).

Answer (score 2):

This [extension (tab-restore)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-restore/dbndgjfafojhfndfgpcibceghelbbnep) do the trick.
you have to enable it of course in incognito tabs, from the Extensions page.
Then you can reopen closed tabs in incognito mode.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes I use it everyday

Answer (score 1):

Cookies won't be stored in Incognito mode. Therefore, your purpose of sharing/storing different cookies(you wrote so in comment to 'Traveling Tech Guy') won't work in Incognito. I guess you are looking at something like accessing different online accounts(facebook, yahoo mail) in two windows. If that is the case you can easily do it with two different browsers, say Firefox and chrome. I do the same when I have to access different accounts with same service provider. In Gmail you can directly sign in to another account in same browser.

Answer (score 1):

As this [post on the Chrome help forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1570bee713018e83&hl=en) notes, Incognito mode specifically doesn't remember your history, so there's no way for it reopen what it doesn't remember.

Answer (score 0):

You can either temporarily save a live session with “Off The Record History” but it will be lost when you crash or if you reboot.

Alternatively, you can permanently store all of your session windows INCLUDING the incognito ones using “Session Manager”. However SM saves incognito windows as normal ones.

So, then you can use “Session Buddy” to automatically save sessions periodically but you can also manually save a session and give it a name. SB too saves all tabs as normal ones, but you can convert any group of tabs (window) to incognito while in the SB window and save that.

The only feature SB and SM don’t have is a memory of the history of each tab, so if you crash you can only start from the last iteration of each tab … but hey, that’s still something, right?

You can always refer to your browser’s “History” function, but it won’t exist for the incognito tabs. However, that’s better than losing it all, isn’t it?

[image: Screenshot showing incognito window in SB]

Answer (score -2):

Reopen-Tabs is an extension that works inside of chrome. Just enable it inside of the extensions